# jquery parseInt nan in firefox

Tags: jquery, parseint

The following line of code:

```
$border_width = parseInt($('#jma_border_element').css('border-width'));
console.log($border_width);
```

The excepted value 5. It works in chrome, but nan in firefox(18.0.2)

Comment: try either `border-left-width` or `borderWidth`

Comment: Show the HTML this applies to. A simple jsFiddle has no issues with your code.

Comment: It could fail because `border-width` could be `''` or something like `px` which is not a valid number

Comment: which is the browser used?

Comment: try alerting `$('#jma_border_element').css('border-width')` and see if it is a valid int in firefox

Comment: @Archer border-left-width worked. thx

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can flag it as correct for future users then - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`border-width` is inadvisable to use since the four borders can all have a different width, style and colour, so some browsers only recognise the individual values.  If you know for sure that they're all the same then simply use this...

```
$border_width = parseInt($('#jma_border_element').css('border-left-width'), 10);
```